# Cuda5, Ubuntu 12.04, OpenCV cuDeviceGetAttribute Error

Tags: opencv, ubuntu-12.04

OpenCV had previously installed properly on my machine with a CUDA capable card. After installing the Cuda 5 toolkit, OpenCV fails to build from source with the following error, ../../lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.1: error: undefined reference to 'cuDeviceGetAttribute'. I'm sort of stuck here and not sure what to do with it. I'm sort of a noob when it comes to bulding stuff from source. The toolkit is fine though, I'm able to compile Cuda code. Any ideas on how to fix this? Directions toward a solution would be great too!

EDIT - make output

```
[  4%] Built target opencv_core
[  5%] Built target opencv_ts
[ 12%] Built target opencv_imgproc
[ 15%] Built target opencv_highgui
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_perf_core
../../lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.1: error: undefined reference to 'cuDeviceGetAttribute'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_perf_core] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you post a short snippet of the actual error output, showing the compile command line that generated the error, as well as the full error text/description.

Comment: [**This**](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/Error-compiling-OpenCV-with-CUDA-td7580604.html) or [**that**](http://code.opencv.org/issues/2105) might help you. Try to install the developer drivers.

Comment: See if you can find the actual link command that is generating the undefined reference error, and see if it is including `-lcuda` or not.  If not, see if you can find the right place in the makefile to add `-lcuda` if linking with nvcc or (more likely) `-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda` if linking with g++.